# Image Segregation: Algorithm to draw a closed loop containing only one kind of object

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I have a picture containing two different types of already identified objects.(Ex. Blue and Red dots). Is there a way to find a path encircling only one kind of object (blue dots) without including the others so that there is one closed region at the end?

[image: Example]

Comment: I would try writing some code to find the centroid of the objects (check out this [link](https://www.learnopencv.com/find-center-of-blob-centroid-using-opencv-cpp-python/)) and then creating line segments to connect the centroids together. Then you could try expanding the width of the line until the point where it collides with the other points.

Comment: @Grug did you tried **Active Contour** Algorithm?